# Unable to convert rdd to Dataframe using Case Class

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert rdd into DataFrame using Case Class as follows

1.)Fetching Data from textfile having "id,name,country" saperated by "," but without header

```
val x = sc.textFile("file:///home/hdadmin/records.txt")
```

2.)Creating a case class "rec" with header definition as below:

```
case class rec(id:Int, name:String, country:String)
```

3.) Now I define the transformations

```
val y = x.map(x=>x.split(",")).map(x=>rec(x(0).toInt,x(1),x(2)))
```

4.) Then I imported the implicits library

```
import spark.implicits._
```

5.) Converting rdd to data Frame using toDF method:

```
val z = y.toDF()
```

6.) Now when I try to fetch the records with command below:

```
z.select("name").show()
```

I get the following error:

> 17/05/19 12:50:14 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already
>   stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerSQLExecutionStart(9,show at
>   :49,org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:495)
>   $line105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:49)
>   $line105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:54)
>   $line105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:56)
>   $line105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:58)
>   $line105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:60)
>   $line105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:62)
>   $line105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:64) $line105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:66)
>   $line105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:68)
>   $line105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:70)
>   $line105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:72)
>   $line105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:74)
>   $line105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:76)
>   $line105.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:78)
>   $line105.$read$$iw$$iw.(:80)
>   $line105.$read$$iw.(:82)
>   $line105.$read.(:84)
>   $line105.$read$.(:88)
>   $line105.$read$.(),== Parsed Logical Plan ==
>   GlobalLimit 21
>   +- LocalLimit 21    +- Project [name#91]
>         +- LogicalRDD [id#90, name#91, country#92]
>
> == Analyzed Logical Plan == name: string GlobalLimit 21
>   +- LocalLimit 21    +- Project [name#91]
>         +- LogicalRDD [id#90, name#91, country#92]
>
> == Optimized Logical Plan == GlobalLimit 21
>   +- LocalLimit 21    +- Project [name#91]
>         +- LogicalRDD [id#90, name#91, country#92]
>
> == Physical Plan == CollectLimit 21
>   +- *Project [name#91]    +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#90,name#91,country#92],org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo@b807ee,1495223414636)
>   17/05/19 12:50:14 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already
>   stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerSQLExecutionEnd(9,1495223414734)
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkContext has been shutdown   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1863)   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1897)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:347)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:39)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2183)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2532)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2182)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2189)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1925)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1924)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2562) 
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:1924)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2139)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:239)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:526)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:486)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:495)   ... 56 elided

Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

After trying the same code for a couple of text files I actually rectified the text format in the text file for any discrepency.

The Column Separator in below code is "," and it was missing at 1 place inside the text file after I scanned it minutely.

```
val y = x.map(x=>x.split(",")).map(x=>rec(x(0).toInt,x(1),x(2)))
```

The code worked fine and gave me results in Structured table format after the changes.

Therefore its important to note that the separator(",", "\t", "|") given inside

```
x.split("")
```

should be same as in source file and throughout the source file.